# redux-saga: redux dispatched action runs and completes only on page load or reload

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I dispatch an action on `componentWillMount` to fetch data from server. The saga fetches data successfully on page `exact url` load and on every reload.

If I navigate to the `url` from some other link in my App, `componentWillMount` fires, but somehow the action is not complete by redux saga.

I tried using `take and fork` and `takeEvery` saga patterns, doesn't work as given in this [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/redux-saga-common-patterns-48437892e11c) link.

My requirement is to fetch latest data from server, every time component mounts.

Comment: Can you add some code on Codesandbox or something like that? Quite hard to help without that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is of **Blocking calls**.

Following links on official docs of redux-saga helped me solve it:

[Non-Blocking Calls](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls.html)

[Troubleshooting](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html)